# Inline editing and add

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using a AngularJS Kendo Grid in my project. I want to implement Add/Edit/Delete in inline with AngularJS.

How can I implement that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I prepared small example to demonstrate a sample Angular JS Kendo UI Grid with CRUD operations. You could check it [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/aLUsa/3).